# Reseting Azure VM deployed from an image using JSON template

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am deploying Azure VMs (with unmanaged disks), that are based on a VHD image. JSON templates used for deployment are stored in my Azure subscription. 
Sometimes I need to reset the machine to the original state - the **manual way to achieve this through the Azure web portal** is:

1. Open the resource group, delete VM (while keeping other resources).
2. Going to the storage account and deleting VHD that served as OS disk for the machine.
3. Go back to the Resource group -> Deployment -> select last Deployment -> Redeploy.

**I want to do this programmatically using PowerShell.** All the steps are quite easily achievable except for the last one - running redeployment.

This is my PowerShell code:

```
# Authenticate to Azure Account
Login-AzAccount

$vm =  Get-AzVM | Out-GridView -Title "Select machine to be reset to factory state" -PassThru
$groupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName


#Stop the VM
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Force

#Delete VM
#Remove-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name

#Getting storage context, blob name and deleting VHD (blob)
$disk = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "myStorageAccountResourceGroupName" -Name "myStorageAccountName"


#Get storage context
$storageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccount.StorageAccountName)[0].Value
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
$container = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context -Name 'vhds'
$blobName = $disk.Name + ".vhd"
$blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $context -Blob $blobName

#Delete Blob
$blob | Remove-AzStorageBlob
```

Now for the last step - I can get the last Resource group deployment and set up a new deployment with *-RollbackToLastDeployment* parameter.

```
#Redeploy Group
$deployments = Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment $groupName
$deployment = $deployments[$deployments.size - 1]

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deployment.DeploymentName -ResourceGroupName $groupName  -TemplateFile <Expects template in local storage> -RollbackToLastDeployment
```

The problem is that the *New-AzResourceGroupDeployment* command expects a JSON template that is on my local disk, but I have my templates stored in the Azure subscription.

Is there any way to use a template that is located in Azure subscription for redeployment of a resource group?

Comment: Where did you store your template? In the storage account? If so, you could use `-TemplateUri` parameter, use the url of the template file in the storage.

Comment: Actually I don't know where the templates are stored "physically" - I created them (and I'm using them from) the Templates section in Azure web interface. When I open the template there, there's no information about it's URI  anywhere (which is weird).

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the place where the template located?

Comment: Actually, no matter where is the template file located, you could convert/copy it to the `.json` file in local, then upload it to the storage, then you will be able to use the  `-TemplateUri` parameter I mentioned.

Comment: @JoyWang The template in the web UI is here > https://snag.gy/kFAcPI.jpg

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow, you could try my solution first.

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang. I tried your solution but it doesn't solve the problem that I don't know the location of my original JSON template.

Comment: See my update, that is the workaround I mentioned, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter where is the template file located, you could convert/copy the template to the `.json`  file in local, then upload it to the storage, then you will be able to use the `-TemplateUri` parameter to deploy the remote template.

Sample:

```
Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName ManageGroup -Name {your-unique-name}

# get the URI with the SAS token
$templateuri = New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Container templates -Blob storage.json -Permission r `
  -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2.0) -FullUri

# provide URI with SAS token during deployment
New-AzResourceGroup -Name ExampleGroup -Location "South Central US"
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleGroup -TemplateUri $templateuri
```

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-powershell-sas-token#provide-sas-token-during-deployment).

**Update**:

Seems we could not find the uri of the Template(preview) in the portal, my workaround is copy the template as a `.json` file in local manually, then upload to the azure blob storage, then use the sample above.

Follow the steps:

1.In the portal, click the `View Template`, you can copy the template and save it as a .`json` file in local.

[image]

2.Then go to the container of your storage account, upload the `.json` file.

[image]

3.Click the `...` of your `.json` file -> `Generate SAS` -> `Generate blob SAS token and URL`, copy the `Blob SAS URL`, it is the `$templateuri` what you need in the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleGroup -TemplateUri $templateuri`. Or you can use `New-AzStorageBlobSASToken` generate it like the sample above.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this will definitely work, allthough it is not optimal.